# How to tackle open set classification problem in Python?

Tags: python, classification, data-mining

I am given an open set Insect classification problem using DNA Barcodes. The goal is to predict **species** labels for testing samples represented in the training set and predict **genus** labels for testing samples not represented in the training set. Given data variables are something like this: 
***gtrain**:* This is a column vector of size 16128. This variable contains genus level labels for each insect instance in the training set. You can think of these as the parent nodes of the leaf nodes in a tree, where leaf nodes are the species and parent nodes are the genera. All instances with the same gtrain value share the same genus. 
***ytrain**:* This is a column vector of size 16128. This variable contains species level labels for each insect instance in the training set. All insect instances with the same ytrain value belong to the same species. 
***emb_train***: This is a 2D matrix of size 16128x1000. Each row in this matrix is a high dimensional encoding (or embedding) of the corresponding nucleotide sequence in the training set. 
***emb_test***: This is a 2D matrix of size 5989x1000. Each row in this matrix is a high dimensional encoding (or embedding) of the corresponding nucleotide sequence in the test set.

I can either predict **genus** or **species** labels using the code below by replacing it with **gtrain** or **ytrain** variable:

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(emb_train, gtrain *or* ytrain, test_size=0.3)
classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5)
classifier.fit(xtrain, ytrain.ravel())
ypred=classifier.predict(emb_test)
```

But I think these predictions are inaccurate because as stated above I need to be able to use both **gtrain** and **ytrain** to train my model in some way and make final accurate predictions on **emb_test**. I am unable to do so this.

Can someone provide some guidance/resources/ideas on how to tackle a problem like this? I can provide more info if something is unclear about the problem.

Comment: Does your training dataset contain any examples that have no species label but only genus label? Otherwise, how would your model learn to predict __genus__ labels?

Comment: @greeness Yes, emb_train consist of species and genus labels. ytrain labels are subclasses of gtrain. For emb_test I have to decide if a sequence is from ytrain and determine its label otherwise if it is not then determine its gtrain label. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If **gtrain** are the parent labels for **y_train** (IIUC, to visualize all the labels, we could connect the nodes of genus labels to their corresponding species children labels into a depth-2 tree), we could learn to predict both genus label and species label at training time. If I am doing this, I will simply concatenate the label output using both genus label space and species label space.

Let's assume your genus space is 100 (you have 100 unique genus categories), and your species space is 1000 (you have 1000 unique species across all genus).

```
Your gtrain is 1x16128, this could be transformed to 100x16128 one hot-vector per row.
Your ytrain is 1x16128, this could be transformed to 1000x16128 one hot-vector per row.
After concatenation, you have a label with shape [1100, 16128].
```

Your could build a model that uses the 1000-dimensional input embedding, connects to a few hidden fully-connected neural network layers and finally connect to the 1100-dimensional output.

At training time, in each step, picks a small batch of examples (say 64 examples out of 16128 totally).

```
input: 64 x 1000 (batch size x embedding dimension)
output: 64 x 1100 (batch size x output label dimension)
```

simply reduce cross-entropy loss at output.
At prediction time, you can use some heuristic. For example,

- **based on the confidence of species output**. if all logits from species output nodes are low (the threshold value can be determined with a validation dataset), you probably could predict nothing at species level, but then pick the top prediction from the genus logits.
- **consider the mutual agreement** on the prediction from genus-level logits and species-level logits. IIUC, suppose one genus label has very high logit, but all the corresponding species logits are low (and also vice versa), this could be considered as a "disagreement" thus triggering the logic of not predicting species label but only the genus-level label.

**Edit**: I also look at your code that uses random forest. In that case, you could build two classifiers using the same embedding feature as input, one predicts into genus label and the other predicts into species label. At inference time, you run two classifiers in parallel, and get both genus-level predictions and species-level predictions. Then you could use the similar heuristics above to decide the final prediction.